# Regex Exclude folder from path

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a bunch of files like these

```
/foo/bar/specs/d.js
/foo/bar/spec/d.js
/foo/bar/specs/v.js
/foo/bar/specs/v.js
/node_modules/bar/specs/v.js
```

I need a regex that will exclude everything under node_modules

Something like this:

```
(?!node_modules)\/.*\/specs\/.*\.js
```

Unfortunately it isnt working

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Here, take this [sword](https://regexr.com/). It will serve you well walking through the `regex` forest.

Comment: @Learnonhardway it's a blunt one :)

Comment: We need more information about your specific use case in order to recommend an appropriate solution to your problem. It seems likely that you're overthinking the problem.  Is this pattern matching for a preprocessor such as webpack?

Comment: @JasonWarta am just loading up a bunch of files from diff dirs.... need to exclude the ones under node_modules

Comment: Try `^\/(?!node_modules\/).*\/specs\/.*\.js$` or  `\/(?!node_modules\/).*\/specs\/.*\.js`

Comment: I suppose exclude everything that matches `/^\/?node_modules\/.*/` should do the trick

Comment: @Learnonhardway I actually love the sword, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably something like this?

```js
let arr = [
    '/foo/bar/specs/d.js',
    '/foo/bar/specs/d.js',
    '/foo/bar/specs/v.js',
    '/foo/bar/specs/v.js',
    '/node_modules/bar/specs/v.js'
]

arr.forEach(s => console.log(/^\/(?!node_modules).*\/.*\/specs\/.*\.js/.test(s)))
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I wanted the reverse... Select everything but node_modules

Comment: @revo he was replying to my previous edit, in which I have done the exactly opposite way...

Comment: You don't need all that extra slashes: `^\/(?!node_modules).*\/specs\/.*\.js$`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that gets .ts and .js files that are not in the .git or node_modules folder:

```
^(?!.*\/(node_modules|\.git)\/).*(.ts|.js)$
```

Explanation:

- Start of string: `^`
- Not in group: `(?!.*\/(node_modules|\.git)\/)`
- Include file types group: `(.ts|.js)`
- End of string: `$`